# Checkpoint sync source for Ethereum beacon chain node

Tags: synchronization, beacon-chain, lighthouse

Ethereum beacon chain nodes like Lighthouse and Prysm offer [checkpoint sync](https://lighthouse-book.sigmaprime.io/checkpoint-sync.html) to get the node synced faster. How can I get a node that I can pass as `--checkpoint-sync-url` to `lighthouse` so that I can perform a checkpoint sync when spinning up new beacon chain node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to popular infrastructure providers like [Infura](https://infura.io/) or [QuickNode](https://www.quicknode.com/), you can now use various public endpoints from [the Ethereum Beacon Chain checkpoint sync endpoints](https://eth-clients.github.io/checkpoint-sync-endpoints/) list. Endpoints from that list often use [the checkpointz project](https://github.com/samcm/checkpointz).

Answer (score 1):

--checkpoint-sync-url https://[PROJECT-ID]:[PROJECT-SECRET]@eth2-beacon-mainnet.infura.io

Answer (score 0):

You can sign up for a [free Infura beacon node](https://infura.io/) and use it as a source for `--checkpoint-sync-url`.